# Sharepoint Chart Web Part x-axis problem

Tags: list, chart-web-part

I'm trying to create a simple chart from a list in sharepoint showing the total revenue billed for each month.

So the Y axis will show the amount billed ($) and the x axis will show Jan, Feb, Mar etc. But when i connect it to the list, the x axis shows Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Jan, Feb, Feb, Feb, Feb, Mar, Mar, Mar (you get the point!) rather than combining all the January revenues into one column, all the February revenues into 1 column etc etc.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you :)

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Is the web part a custom web part, or is it an OOTB web part?